# How to change the size/width of an input field with Code Igniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

How can I ensure that my `input field` is a certain size using `codeigniter`? Im using `'size'` attribute at the minute but its not working.

Current code:

```
$dataArray= array(

'name'=> 'test',
'id'=> 'test',
'value'=>'10',
'size'=> '2',
);


echo form_input($dataArray);
```

However the input box is still taking up the full width of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a **class** like:

```
$dataArray= array(
'name'=> 'test',
'id'=> 'test',
'value'=>'10',
'size'=> '2',
'class'=>'custom_input'// here i have added a class
);


echo form_input($dataArray);
```

Then use this in your **css** file like `style.css`:

```
.custom_input{
width:50px;/*use according to your need*/
height:30px;/*use according to your need*/
}
```

Add this line in your `<head>` section part like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourpath/style.css">
```

And if you don't want external CSS, use follwing:

```
$dataArray= array(
'name'=> 'test',
'id'=> 'test',
'value'=>'10',
'size'=> '2',
'style'=>'width:50px;height:50px'// here i have added a class
);


echo form_input($dataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The size element may not necessarily change the width or the height of the input depending on the setup you have in CSS.

I would recommend setting the styles manually using the 'style' option:

```
$dataArray= array(
    'name'=> 'test',
    'id'=> 'test',
    'value'=>'10',
    'style'=> 'width: 100px;',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this you can add style attribute like this

```
$dataArray= array(
'name'=> 'test',
'id'=> 'test',
'value'=>'10',
'size'=> '2',
'style'=>'width:30px;height:300px'// here i have added a class
);


echo form_input($dataArray);
```

or you can do it in other file and can link it to your page